# GWT capture event in RichTextArea or in IFrame

Tags: events, gwt, copy-paste, richtextarea

I have a RichTextArea

```java
 private RichTextArea richTextArea;
```

and I'm trying to capture a paste event like this:

```java
DOM.sinkEvents((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) richTextArea.getElement(), com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.ONPASTE);
DOM.setEventListener((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) richTextArea.getElement(), new EventListener(){
  @Override public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
     switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
        case Event.ONPASTE: Window.alert("hey");break;
     }
   }
});
```

But it doesn't work, when I paste text on the richTextArea the alert is not triggered.

Any idea how to capture this paste event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the event to the `RichTextArea`, which actually is an `iframe`, but to it's body.

Although you could use `jsni`, I would use [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) because its simplicity:

```java
// First attach the widget to the DOM
RootPanel.get().add(richTextArea);

// We only can bind events to the content, once the iframe document has been created, 
// and this happens after it has been attached. Note that richtTextArea uses a timeout
// to initialize, so we have to delay the event binding as well
$(richTextArea).delay(1, lazy().contents().find("body").bind(Event.ONPASTE, new Function(){
  @Override public boolean f(Event e) {
    Window.alert("OnPaste");
    return true;
  }
}).done());
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the rendered HTML of `RichTextArea` ? it's an `iframe` not an actual `textarea input` type. it sets the user input under a `body` element. So that's why you don't get sinked `onpaste` events. For example if you listen to `onpaste` on `TextArea` widget it works fine.

```
private static class MyTextArea extends TextArea
    {
        public MyTextArea()
        {
            sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);              
        }

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
        {
            if(event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONPASTE)
            {
                Window.alert("text pasted !");
            }
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

maybe you can bind a handler to that iframe body element using JSNI and get the callback on that event (haven't tried it though )

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, the native (JSNI) solution would be something like:

```js
setPastehandler(richTextArea.getElement());

private native void setPasteHandler(Element e) /*-{
    e.contentDocument.onpaste = function (event) {
        alert("pasted!");
    };
}-*/;
```